# What will be the output of the following C++ program assuming dynamic scoping?

Tags: c++, function, dynamic, global-variables, scoping

What will be the output of the following C++ program assuming dynamic scoping?
I have turboc++ compiler in which the output shown is using static scoping and the answer is as follows:
8
6
50
Now, my doubt is that the output assuming dynamic scoping will be
either
207
104
52
-- or --
207
104
50

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int n=1;
void printn(int x)
{
  cout<<x+n<<"\n";
}
void increment()
{
  n=n+2;
  printn(n);
}
void main()
{
  clrscr();
  int n;
  n=200;
  printn(7);
  n=50;
  increment();
  cout<<n;
  getch();
}
```

Comment: The question is nonsensical because C++ does not use dynamic scoping. What is your practical programming problem? Do you want to use dynamic scoping in C++?

Comment: If C++ uses static scoping then I will want you to answer if this kind of code was written in any language that support Dynamic Scoping, then what will be the output of that changed code in that language.

Comment: This is not a practical programming question. StackOverflow is for solving actual programming problems you are having, not for discussing theoretical behavior in imaginary programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Any conforming compiler will give you errors and not output anything, because you

```
#include<iostream.h>
```

after which you use

```
cout << ...
```

without qualifying it with `std::` or having a `using` directive and because of

```
void main()
```

After you've fixed these, any conforming C++ compiler will output

```
8 
6 
50
```

Comment: yeah, you are right and I have got the output as
8
6
50
but what will be the output in case of dynamic scoping as i am studying Principles of Programming Languages from the book by author Robert Sebesta, I am confused of the output in case of Dynamic Scoping.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty standard question in PL courses, I think.

Assuming dynamic scoping (and a mutant C++)

```
207
104
52
```

Hard to test, since your question is probably a theoretical exercise in understanding scoping. However, Perl (which is usually (and thankfully) statically scoped) supports dynamic scoping if you ask it to, via the `local` keyword:

```
my $x = 1;    # default lexical scope
local $y = 1; # dynamically scoped.
```

So, if you feel up to it, you can rewrite your program in Perl and try it for kicks:

```perl
sub println {
  my $x = shift;
  printf "%d\n", $x + $n;
}

sub increment {
  $n = $n + 2;
  println($n);
}

sub main {
  local $n = 200; # $n will be dynamically scoped!
  println(7);
  $n = 50;
  increment();
  print "$n\n";
}

main();
```

Gives you `207 104 52`.

Comment: Thanks Faiz for your reply... But what do you mean by mutant C++?

Comment: @Ceres111 - an imaginary language that was once C++ but turned into something very strange ;-)

Comment: Hmm, I too think that the answer should be 207 104 52... my doubt was on 52 (or 50) but 52 must be the correct one. Thanks for your help